# C# -> Entity Framework 6.1.3 -> Composite nullable foreign key string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm integrating against an external system where they use a lot of composite keys and often `strings`. I'm now facing a problem where I need to make a composite foreign key `nullable`. If the value would be an `int` i could just mark it as nullable with `int?` but this is not possible here. I think I have to use fluent api but if it is possible with data annotations that is the preferred way. To make it even harder the first part of the foreign key is also used as the first part for the primary key and thus can not be nullable.

`BillCurrency` and `DisbCurrency` for `FeeCalculation` are the keys that needs to be nullable below. The models created are valid apart from the nullable part.

The obvious exception message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.FeeCalculations_dbo.ExchangeRates_BusinessSystemId_BillCurrency". The conflict occurred in database "Project.Database", table
>   "dbo.ExchangeRates". The statement has been terminated.

```
public class FeeCalculation
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public string BillCurrency { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,BillCurrency")]
    public virtual ExchangeRate BillCurrencyObject { get; set; }

    public string DisbCurrency { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,DisbCurrency")]
    public virtual ExchangeRate DisbCurrencyObject { get; set; }

}

public class ExchangeRate
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string ForeignCurrency { get; set; }

    public string HomeCurrency { get; set; }

    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public double Rate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `string` columns are nullable by default. Most likely the problem is coming from the shared `BusinessSystemId` column which is part of the PK (hence is required). I'm not sure EF (databases) supports "partially" nullable composite FK.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes I know strings are nullable. Quick fix is to remove the FK but would be nice with some database integrity anyway.

Comment: The point was I don't believe you can have such FK in relational database. Are you mapping to an existing database or creating your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was nothing wrong with the models, it was a `FeeCalculation` value that was corrupt and tried to insert a key that did not exist in `ExchangeRate`.